# Can anyone identify this bird - small flock in ireland?

Tags: species-identification, species

I saw small birds in a flock of about 6 or 8.

Here are details that can be seen on my best photo - The beak looks pointed and also the legs are quite long and the eye has a bar across it.

[image]

I have a recording - how do I share it??

Comment: The body shape and colour reminds me of a [greenfinch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_greenfinch) (_Chloris chloris_). They also form flocks. However, the beak on your pictures doesn't look very 'finch-like'. Can you tell us anything about the beak shape, or do you have a picture, where it's better visible?

Comment: the beak seems to be pointed - the birds were far away - i will try for a closer shot if they return -

Comment: the beak looks pointed and also the legs are quite long and the eye has a bar across it-

Comment: Maybe edit your question add these additional information there. Not everyone reads all the comments :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz You can probably make an answer from your comment.

Comment: I also first thought of green finches, but they have a much stronger beak.

Comment: @Remi.b Richard's comment about the pointed beak made me doubt. I'm still searching for a better fit.

Comment: They're definitely not greenfinch. The horizontal bar across the eye rules that out. I think yellow-crowned wagtail (Motacilla flava ssp. flavissima) is a better fit. See https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Motacilla_flava_flavissima,_Kingsbury,_Warwickshire_1.jpg.

Comment: @bshane I think Motacilla would have more visible stripes on the wings.

Comment: @bli: not always. Worn plumage loses a lot of the distinct scalloping. e.g., https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hlasek.com%2Ffoto%2Fmotacilla_flava_da5089.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hlasek.com%2Fmotacilla_flava.html&docid=uMycFdL-fJqLvM&tbnid=7l0k0nvS20RrGM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjmspmyktzcAhVSQd4KHSL5C3cQMwiHAShEMEQ..i&w=626&h=500&client=ubuntu&bih=1079&biw=1920&q=motacilla%20flava&ved=0ahUKEwjmspmyktzcAhVSQd4KHSL5C3cQMwiHAShEMEQ&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: Thanks Chris - If they return I will try for a recording - however the Chiffchaff, Willow Warbler and Wood Warbler are described as having black beaks - these have distinct light coloured beaks - perhaps juveniles / male-female differences??

Comment: @user45303 - You can make edits to your post using your original account (Richard). You do not need to create another account. Well, if you have forgotten your password then [see here what to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95358/i-lost-control-of-my-account-before-registering-can-it-be-recovered). For now, Iam rejecting your edit.

Answer (score 7):

With the new image it is still hard, but I think I identified the bird. I think this is a Willow warbler (Phylloscopus trochilus) which is pretty common in Europe.

The drawing from the Royal Bird Protection Society (source [here](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/willow-warbler)) is pretty similar.

[image]

Unfortunately, there are two pretty similar birds living in Ireland which can be confused with the Willow warbler. These are the [Chiffchaff](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/chiffchaff/) and the [Wood warbler](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/wood-warbler/). Differences are small, the Chiffchaff has dark legs and a smaller eye stripe (both of which the bird in your image has not), while the wood warbler lives in woods and has a more yellow breast (and is also much more rare). The links provide audio files with the songs of each bird, this should help you making a final decision, as they are pretty distinct.

Comment: In the US warblers typical travel in small loose flocks.